# How should i fox my code, if there is an error: '>=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'list'?

Tags: python, list, typeerror

I need to find the largest number in the list, and it tells me there's a problem with the array: TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'list'.

```
arr=[[4, 3, 5], 2]
num=0

while num!=2:
    big=0
    for i in range(len(arr[0])):
        for j in range(len(arr[0])):

            if arr[0][i] >= arr[0][j] and arr[0][i] >= big:
                big=arr[i]

print(big)
```

I just want to find the largest number- which is 5 in this context, but I don't really know how to fix that problem.

Comment: Get out of the habit of using `for index in range(len(list)):`. Use `for item in list:` or `for index, item in enumerate(list):`

Comment: `big=arr[i]` sets `big` to the list `[4, 3, 5]` on the first iteration. So, the next iteration, when you try to compare `arr[0][i] >= big`, `big` is a `list`, while `arr[0][i]` is an integer.

Comment: You probably mean `big=arr[0][i]`

Comment: Why not just `big=max(arr[0])`?

Comment: You don't need nested loops to find the largest number in a list.

Comment: You have an infinite `while` loop, since you never change `num`.

Comment: tnx all! it helped!

Answer (score 0):

One option to find the maximum in a nested list could be to use a recursive function:

```
arr=[[4, 3, 5], 2]

def nested_max(l):
    return max(nested_max(x) if isinstance(x, list) else x for x in l)

nested_max(arr)
# 5
```